# How do you read an html template in a python script?

Tags: python, html

I have a file called html_form.py that contains the html I want to use for the output of my cgi script in python, hw.py. However, I'm not sure how to call it in hw.py. Advice? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In hw.py write:

```
import html_form
```

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html